# Overwrite on a txt file from AMPL

Tags: ampl

I have a result I want to save in a .txt file. So I use this line to save a result `k`:

```
param OutputFile symbolic := "output.txt";
print k >> (OutputFile);
```

However, I may run the script several times which means I will open an existing file and add lines to it. What I want to do is **overwrite** on the file output.txt so I will not have the previous runs results.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should overwrite :

```
 k > (OutputFile);
```

While this appends :

```
 k >> (OutputFile);
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped

Answer (score 6):

To overwrite a file that you have previously been writing in an AMPL session, first close the file:

```
close (OutputFile);
```

Then use > to overwrite the file:

```
print k > (OutputFile);
```

This deletes the file and then opens a new, empty file with the same name. Note that once the file is open, > and >> both append to it. A complete description of AMPL file redirection is given in section [12.7 General facilities for manipulating output](https://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/15-display.pdf#page=33) of the AMPL book.